# Checking the state of Parse email verification from swift

Tags: swift, email, parse-platform, verification

After parse has sent the email to the entered email address, how can I check wether or not that email address has been verified from within swift and only then allow the user to log in to the app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse `User` object, has field `emailVerified`. So when user log in to the app you can check it:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(email, password: password) { (user, error) in

  if error == nil{
    if let verified = user["emailVerified"] as? Bool{
      if verified == true{
       // log in
      }else{
       // show that email isn't verified
      }
    }else{
      // show that email isn't verified
    }
  }
}
```